# What is the current, correct way to retrieve an SESBackend from Moto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, moto

I need access to the SESBackend object behind Moto's [mock_ses](https://github.com/spulec/moto/tree/master/moto/ses) library, so that I can check sent messages have the right properties. The [Moto documentation for SES](http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/services/ses.html) currently only shows the basic decorator wrapping syntax.

I've got something working, but it feels very clunky, and I am thinking there must be a better way of doing this:

```
import pytest
import boto3    
from moto import mock_ses
from moto.core.utils import AccountSpecificBackend
from moto.ses.models import SESBackend

# **************************************
# *** Is this code really necessary? ***
# **************************************
def get_ses_backend(ses_object) -> SESBackend:
    for key, value in ses_object.backends.items():
        if isinstance(value, AccountSpecificBackend):
            return value['global']

def test_my_email_function():
    with mock_ses() as ses_object:
        ses_conn = boto3.client("ses", region_name='eu-west-2')

        backend = get_ses_backend(ses_object)

        # Do some stuff with boto3 ses

        assert (len(backend.sent_messages) == 1)
```

I'm quite new to mocking and moto, so it could just be I am not looking in the right place. Someone asked [a related question back in June on the project GitHub](https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/5272), but I don't understand how to apply the given answer to my own case. I'm currently using Moto 4.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lowercase `ses_backend` to access the instance of the SESBackend-class:

```
from moto.core import DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID
from moto.ses import ses_backends
def get_ses_backend() -> SESBackend:
    return ses_backends[DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID]["global"]
```

Note that the `ses_object` alias after `mock_ses()` is no longer necessary, so you could simplify the decorator:

```
with mock_ses():
    ses_conn = boto3.client("ses", region_name='eu-west-2')

    backend = get_ses_backend()
```

### Documentation links:

The above example uses the default account. See the documentation if you want to change the account to something else: http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/multi_account.html

The docs for the SNS-service show the pattern of accessing the backend, albeit for a different service: http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/services/sns.html